# strange segmentation fault, assembly (x86)

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following x86 code:

```
    .section    .rodata
    .text
    subl    $440, %esp
    movl    %esp, %ecx
    subl    $24, %esp
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    $4, %edx
    imul    %edx, %eax
    movl    $2, %edx
    addl    %ecx, %eax
    movl    %edx, 24(%eax)
    movl    $0, %eax
    nop
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
```

This program gives `segmentation fault (Core Dumped)` when compiled using gcc. Removing `movl    %edx, 24(%eax)` however removes the error. I am new to assembly, please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You have code before the `main` label, so that code is not executed but would be required because that's setting up `ecx`. You should move those 3 lines down to after the `andl $-16, %esp` line.

Comment: (in reply to deleted comment asking about moving the code to the beginning of `main`): That is allowed but won't work, as you have seen. The fault in that case will be at the end of the function because you are not restoring the stack properly. `ebp` is used by the `leave` instruction, so it must be set to the initial value of `esp`.

Comment: @Jester That does work. However I wanted to change the stack pointer before execution of main (I don't want the stack pointer to change in the prologue). Is there a way to do that? Please post your reply as an answer so that I can accept it.